# What's the $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x^2}{\sqrt{1+x\sin x} - \sqrt{\cos x}}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

This exercise is kind of hard for me to understand. Could somebody clarify it step by step please?  $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x^2}{\sqrt{1+x\sin x} - \sqrt{\cos x}}$$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: Is the denominator $\sin(x^2)$ or $(\sin(x))^2$?

Comment: hmm..this was an exercise the teacher gave us, i'm having some trouble multiplying the denominator and numerator with an expression or number that would give me sinx/x=1. No idea where she got this exercise from.

Comment: @BernardMassé it is as i've written it: sin(x^2)

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**

It can be solved using [L'Hospital rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x^2}{\sqrt{1+x\sin x} - \sqrt{\cos x}} &= \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2 x \cos \left(x^2\right)}{\frac{\sin (x)}{2 \sqrt{\cos (x)}}+\frac{\sin (x)+x \cos (x)}{2 \sqrt{x \sin (x)+1}}} \\
&=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{4 x \cos \left(x^2\right)}{\frac{\sin (x)}{\sqrt{\cos (x)}}+\frac{\sin (x)+x \cos (x)}{\sqrt{x \sin (x)+1}}} \\
&=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{4 \cos \left(x^2\right)-8 x^2 \sin \left(x^2\right)}{\sqrt{\cos (x)}+\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{2 \cos ^{\frac{3}{2}}(x)}-\frac{(\sin (x)+x \cos (x))^2}{2 (x \sin (x)+1)^{3/2}}+\frac{2 \cos (x)-x \sin (x)}{\sqrt{x \sin (x)+1}}}\\
&=\dfrac{4}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Method 2:** We can use [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x^2}{\sqrt{1+x\sin x} - \sqrt{\cos x}} &= \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x^2+o\left(x^3\right)}{\frac{3 x^2}{4}+o\left(x^3\right)} \\
&=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x^2}{\frac{3 x^2}{4}}\\
&=\dfrac{4}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

See [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/m120/taylorLimits.pdf) for a tutorial in how to evaluate limits with Taylor Series.

Comment: Oh, we haven't learned neither of these rules/theorems yet. But yeah, im going to look into them. Thanks!

Comment: @GreasyLlama I've just added a tutorial for evaluating limits with Taylor series.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's $\sin^2 x$, here's an attempt :
Let :
$$L=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2 x}{\sqrt{1+x\sin x} - \sqrt{\cos x}}$$
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin^2 x)(\sqrt{1+x\sin x} +\sqrt{\cos x})}{1+x\sin x - \cos x}
\\
&=2\times\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+x\sin x - \cos x}\\
&=2\times \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{1+x\sin x - \cos x}{\sin^2 x}}\\
&=2\times\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{x\sin x}{\sin^2 x}+\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2 x}}\\
&=2\times\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{x}{\sin x}+\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}\\
&=2\times \frac{1}{1+1\times \frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{4}{3}
\end{align}
Hence (if it's in the expression $\sin^2 x$) :
$$L=\frac{4}3$$
Otherwise you can see @FFjet's answer, but I'm not quiet sure that you'll understand it if you're a high school student !

Good luck.

Comment: In fact in this problem it is not important whether the numerator is $\sin(x^2)$ or $\sin(x)^2$, for that they share the same taylor expansion (to order $2$) at $0$, that is $x^2+o(x^3)$

Comment: it is sin(x^2). I don't get where the "2" in the fourth line comes from...and yeah @FFjet 's method of the "Taylor series" looks kinda interesting ngl.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{1+x\sin x} +\sqrt{\cos x}= \sqrt{1+0}+\sqrt{1}=2$ here where it came from.

Taylor series is a wonderful tool, I bet that you'll adore it !